# Manipulation of two lists of strings and integers

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have the following lists:

```
l1 = {{"letter.a.a", "1"}, {"letter.b.b", "1"}, {"letter.c.c", 
    "1"}, {"letter.d.d", "1"}, {"letter.e.e", "1"}, {"letter.f.f", 
    "1"}};
l2 = {{"f", 10}, {"c", 9}, {"e", 8}, {"b", 7}, {"d", 6}, {"a", 5}};
```

I want to replace the integers in `l2` with `"1"`s in `l1` appropriately such that I get:

```
{{"letter.a.a", 5}, {"letter.b.b", 7}, {"letter.c.c", 
        9}, {"letter.d.d", 6}, {"letter.e.e", 8}, {"letter.f.f", 
        10}}
```

Given the strings in `l1` and `l2` are slightly different I wonder how one can do this?

Update: In a  more complex system I have:

```
l1 = {{"Food.ALMOND.ALMONDCINNAMON", 
   "1"}, {"Food.BLACK_CURRANT.BLACK_CURRANTCORN", 
   "1"}, {"Food.BELL_PEPPER.BELL_PEPPERLIME", "1"}}
l2 = {{"BLACK_CURRANTCORN", 4}, {"BELL_PEPPERLIME", 
   3}, {"ALMONDCINNAMON", 2}}
```

Here strings are words that need to be separated. How would one solve it for such lists? I think `StringTake` method fails for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
assoc = Association[Rule @@@ l2];
l3 = l1;
l3[[All, 2]] = assoc /@ StringTake[l1[[All, 1]], -1] ;
l3
```

> {{"letter.a.a", 5}, {"letter.b.b", 7}, {"letter.c.c", 9}, {"letter.d.d", 6}, {"letter.e.e", 8}, {"letter.f.f", 10}}

Alternatively,

```
l3 = l1;
l3[[All, 2]] = assoc /@ StringSplit[l1[[All, 1]], "."][[All, -1]];
l3
```

> same result

**Update:**

```
ClearAll[f]
f = Module[{assoc = Association[Rule @@@ #2], l3 = #}, 
    l3[[All, 2]] = assoc /@ StringSplit[l3[[All, 1]], "."][[All, -1]];l3] &;

l1b = {{"Food.ALMOND.ALMONDCINNAMON", "1"}, {"Food.BLACK_CURRANT.BLACK_CURRANTCORN", "1"}, 
  {"Food.BELL_PEPPER.BELL_PEPPERLIME", "1"}};
l2b = {{"BLACK_CURRANTCORN", 4}, {"BELL_PEPPERLIME", 3}, {"ALMONDCINNAMON", 2}};


f[l1, l2]
```

> {{"Food.ALMOND.ALMONDCINNAMON", 
>     2}, {"Food.BLACK_CURRANT.BLACK_CURRANTCORN", 
>     4}, {"Food.BELL_PEPPER.BELL_PEPPERLIME", 3}}

Comment: I see, so the main method is to use `StringTake`, but what if the system is more complex? i.e. suppose we have words. Let me make a edit for more generalised case.

Comment: I just updated the question, please see.

Comment: @William, updated.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, Another possibility might be

```
l1[[All, 2]]=Flatten[StringCases[First@#,"letter." ~~ c_ :> c]& /@ l1] /. (Rule @@@ l2)
```

which make `l1` as

```
{{"letter.a.a", 5}, {"letter.b.b", 7}, {"letter.c.c", 
  9}, {"letter.d.d", 6}, {"letter.e.e", 8}, {"letter.f.f", 10}}
```

I think @kglr using association looks more direct.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun also :)

```
Map[{#[[1, 1]], #[[2, 2]]} &, GatherBy[Flatten[{l1, l2}, 1], (Last@StringSplit[#[[1]], "."]) &]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = 
 {{"letter.a.a", "1"}, {"letter.b.b", "1"}, {"letter.c.c", "1"}, 
  {"letter.d.d", "1"}, {"letter.e.e", "1"}, {"letter.f.f", "1"}};

b = {{"f", 10}, {"c", 9}, {"e", 8}, {"b", 7}, {"d", 6}, {"a", 5}};
```

Using `SubsetMap` (new in 12.0)

```
SubsetMap[
 Lookup[
   Rule @@@ b,
   StringPart[First /@ a, -1]] &,
 a,
 {All, -1}]
```

returns

```
{{"letter.a.a", 5}, {"letter.b.b", 7}, {"letter.c.c", 9}, 
 {"letter.d.d", 6}, {"letter.e.e", 8}, {"letter.f.f", 10}}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Lookup`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
subs[products_List, price_List] := Module[{lut = Rule @@@ price},
  {First@#
     , Lookup[lut
      , Last@StringSplit[First@#, "."]
      , "Not found"]
     } & /@ products
  ]
```

---

```
l1 = {{"letter.a.a", "1"}, {"letter.b.b", "1"}, {"letter.c.c", 
    "1"}, {"letter.d.d", "1"}, {"letter.e.e", "1"}, {"letter.f.f", 
    "1"}};
l2 = {{"f", 10}, {"c", 9}, {"e", 8}, {"b", 7}, {"d", 6}, {"a", 5}};

subs[l1, l2]

{{"letter.a.a", 5}, {"letter.b.b", 7}, {"letter.c.c", 
  9}, {"letter.d.d", 6}, {"letter.e.e", 8}, {"letter.f.f", 10}}
```

---

```
l1 = {{"Food.ALMOND.ALMONDCINNAMON", 
    "1"}, {"Food.BLACK_CURRANT.BLACK_CURRANTCORN", 
    "1"}, {"Food.BELL_PEPPER.BELL_PEPPERLIME", "1"}};
l2 = {{"BLACK_CURRANTCORN", 4}, {"BELL_PEPPERLIME", 
    3}, {"ALMONDCINNAMON", 2}};

subs[l1, l2]
```

> {{"Food.ALMOND.ALMONDCINNAMON",    2},
> {"Food.BLACK_CURRANT.BLACK_CURRANTCORN",    4},
> {"Food.BELL_PEPPER.BELL_PEPPERLIME", 3}}

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = 
 {{"letter.a.a", "1"}, {"letter.b.b", "1"}, {"letter.c.c", "1"}, 
  {"letter.d.d", "1"}, {"letter.e.e", "1"}, {"letter.f.f", "1"}};

l2 = {{"f", 10}, {"c", 9}, {"e", 8}, {"b", 7}, {"d", 6}, {"a", 5}};
```

Using `Thread`:

```
(s |-> {First@s[[1]], Last@s[[-1]]}) /@ Thread[{l1, SortBy[l2, First]}]

(*{{"letter.a.a", 5}, {"letter.b.b", 7}, {"letter.c.c", 9},
   {"letter.d.d", 6}, {"letter.e.e", 8}, {"letter.f.f", 10}}*)
```

The above works as long as the list `l1` is in the order provided by the author of the OP. Now suppose that the list `l1` is not in that order, that is, it is in the following order:

```
l1 = 
  {{"letter.f.f", "1"}, {"letter.c.c", "1"}, {"letter.b.b", "1"}, 
   {"letter.a.a", "1"}, {"letter.e.e", "1"}, {"letter.d.d", "1"}};
```

So, we just need to sort l1 using `SortBy` as follows:

```
l3 = SortBy[l1, StringPart[StringReverse[#], 1] &];
```

And finally, proceed as we did at the beginning:

```
(s |-> {First@s[[1]], Last@s[[-1]]}) /@ Thread[{l3, SortBy[l2, First]}]

(*{{"letter.a.a", 5}, {"letter.b.b", 7}, {"letter.c.c", 9},
   {"letter.d.d", 6}, {"letter.e.e", 8}, {"letter.f.f", 10}}*)
```